# Change Android status bar color on home/lock screen based on custom events within an app

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-statusbar

I am currently developing a simple android app which should change the status bar color for home/lock screen based on certain events happening into the background(similar with how the status bar color turns orange when battery level drops under 10%). I know that status bar color can be changed within the application itself but can this be done at the system level without root access?

Many thanks,
Lucian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to make change in color of home/lock screen because just you access to make a change in an activity status bar color and it does not work in all android sdks,

but you can develop a launcher and then make a service for it after that you can pass data to service and then change home/lock screen status bar color.

and the code of services and change status bar color and making launcher is in internet and you can access to them

i hope it was helpful for you !!

if you have some other questions or needs to help ask and then i try to help (:

good luck

Answer (score 0):

To change android status Bar Color see [How to Customize the Status Bar on Android (Without Rooting)](https://www.howtogeek.com/272459/how-to-customize-the-status-bar-on-android-without-rooting/)

Comment: Thanks @mpes but I was looking for a programmatic way to change the status bar color using java code.

Comment: What type of android version do you use?

Comment: I want my app to be used for API level 21 or higher. Currently I am testing only on Android Oreo 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Add on MainActivity.java, `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0x00000000);` also 
see if backgroundColor of AppBar is transparent maybe status bar fonts can't read it.

Comment: I tried but it's only changing color within the app, not the system status bar color, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1)First go 
On colors.xml file
see if you have add already the code inside  the 2  elements , if not put that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
<color name ="purple">#770B7A;</color>

</resources>
```

Write a color in this element `<color name ="purple">`, in my example I name it purple, the color, purple is an example, give whatever color you want.

2)Second go
On MainActivity.java file 
Notice that there is a comment which say //change status color , so under this commend write code

```
 if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
 Window.window=this.getWindow();
 Window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKBROUNDS);
 Window.clearFlag(windowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
 Window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
 }
```

this is a plugin *but be sure to write the name of color you want in this code `(R.color.your_color)`*
 write the name of color like this (R.color.purple), the java doesn't exist the code color so that's why I write
 the name of color. 
Notice: be sure to write the same `color name`,  you use on color.xml file and on MainActivity.java file.